# How to show images on full-screen upon clicking?

Tags: android, zooming

I have a textview that has html content. Html content has some images with some text. I want to shows the image in full screen, and to add ability to zoom in/out with touch.

```
final Spannable html = (Spannable)Html.fromHtml(post.getContent(),new MyImageGetter(PostContent.this, postcontent),null);
for (final ImageSpan span : html.getSpans(0, html.length(), ImageSpan.class)) {
    int flags = html.getSpanFlags(span);
    int start = html.getSpanStart(span);
    int end = html.getSpanEnd(span);
    html.setSpan(new URLSpan(span.getSource()) {
        @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // what i do for full screen image and zoom in/out with touch?
         }
    }, start, end, flags);
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be resolved using WebSettings.
Here is my code snippet.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: but i dont use webview.i use textview.one way is Intent.send image with intent to another activity and show with a imageview in full screen.how can i send an image with intent?